# What is the right way to import custom react native module on Xcode?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm building a custom RN module for iOS and Android. Following some others modules, I notice that the dependencies it's never imported to the module itself, but always imported in the main app. For example for iOS:

[react-native-admob](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob) has Google Mobile Ads SDK as dependency, but the developer has to add on the app.

That said, I have my custom module only building on Xcode, because when I try to run `react-native run-ios` I get the error:

```
info In file included from /Users/.../node_modules/react-native-my-module/ios/MyModuleViewManager.m:2:
/Users/.../node_modules/react-native-my-module/ios/RNMyModule.h:8:9: fatal error: module 'PrebidMobile' not found
@import PrebidMobile;
 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening myapp.xcworkspace
```

What could I be doing wrong, that react-native command can't find the *import* library from *Link Binary With Libraries*?